# What is this class diagram generated from?

Tags: java, uml, symbols, class-diagram

I am given this class diagram. [image]But trying to understand the symbols and pointers it has. 
I googled it for similar images. But no luck.

Can anyone tell me what tool is used to generate this image? (Doesn't seem to be UML).
I need to understand the relationship and what each symbol means in this pic.

Comment: Can't see the diagram

Comment: What did the person who gave it to you say about it? Have you asked him/her?

Comment: It's hard to make heads or tails out of it as all of the important bits have been crossed out. Otherwise it looks UML to me.

Comment: @Vanquish46. Picture is not clear or you don't see the picture at all?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Those are class/interface names. I guess thats not necessary?

Comment: @KevinRave: I guess you're right, that they're not necessary, seeing as you're getting so many knowledgeable and correct answers for your question. <scratch_head />

Comment: @KevinRave: Can't see the picture at all. But other people seem to be talking about it so maybe a problem on my end.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know. Not a single answer yet! :-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tried to provide a better image.

Comment: I think that this doesn't originate from any public API, since the google search for "ManifestCrudService" returns no result!
I'm pretty sure that this is a part of a selfmade ODS connectivity program.

Comment: `"Doesn't seem to be UML"` -- I disagree as it looks to be UML to me showing both interface dependence and what looks like composition dependence.

Comment: why did you just paint on it? does it contain any password or something? while I cannot see the diagram, but it 99% is a uml class diagram because of << interface >>, T : Class, and generalization, gears as method

Comment: @My-Name-Is The question is not about what these classes are, but how the diagram is created, tool. Because, I want to understand the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsing the web I found [.NET Visualizer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/dw-rt-visnetapp/section5.html) which uses very similar icons. Probably your diagram originates from a different version of this tool

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an UML class diagram to me. It's a bit hard to tell with so much crossed out, but I'm guessing the regular -> arrows are use relationships, while the triangular arrows are inherit/implement relations; so standard UML.

Comment: Do you know what the icons at each method mean? Its different in different classes/interfaces

Comment: The ones next to the class/interface names just seem to indicate whether it's a class or interface. The ones inside the boxes I'm guessing are methods (gears) and members (other stuff). The green dots on the gears likely mean those are public.